# Get first word from Smarty Variable

Tags: php, variables, smarty, smarty3

I am using `{$i.domain}` variable in Smarty to get a domain name. Is there any way to get only the first word from the variable `{$i.domain}` in Smarty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
{$i.domain|strstr:' ':true}
```

It is [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function. You can use those functions in Smarty as modifiers.

For example if in PHP I use:

```
$smarty->assign('i', ['domain' => "it's my sample text"]);
```

and in Smarty use the code I showed at the beginning I get result:

> it's

Comment: I tried as you have suggested but it is not displaying anything.

Comment: @KevinS I've edited answer. If it doesn't work for you please write what Smarty version you use and include PHP code where you assign it to Smarty. I also don't know what's the string you try to split.

Comment: I am using latest stable version of smarty. Here is the code that might help `$data['stat']['domain'] = $record['domain'];` `smarty->assign('data', $data);`

Comment: So why in question you used `{$i.domain}` at all? You have `{$data.stat.domain}` and not `{$i.domain}` inside Smarty